# how to add new field in android app by user at run time

Tags: android, android-studio

how to add new field in android app by user at run time. For Example, I have Customer form want to fill by user like following image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtT6B.png)

Now I want to add one more field such as "Mobile Number" from running app not from Android Studio.So in this app user can add any field in this form through this app.
Here user can select multiple fields and its datatype, size and name also. 
Then how to do this?

Comment: you have to add the field by user self and make it visibility gone and just put an option add phone number after clicking that text make the visibility of that field gone to visible by this you can achieve this!!

Comment: Mr.Amarbir Singh how to do that? do you have any sample code example for this?

Comment: Any sample code or example do you have for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do this in an activity class.

You first create a new instance of `EditText`:

```
EditText textfield = new EditText(this);
```

Then you want to set the properties of the `EditText`:

```
textfield.setText(...);
textfield.setHint(...);
textfield.setLayoutParams(...);
textfield.setTextSize(...);
...
```

After that, just add the edit text to the activity:

```
this.addView(textfield);
```

Easy! Right?

Of course not!

The hardest part of this is deciding how you want to layout the views. If you don't like doing that, you can use this alternative way.

First, create an XML layout file, then use XML to design how your view will look. Let's say you want to have a `TextView` on the left and an `EditText` on the right. You just need to put a text view and an edit text in a horizontal linear layout.

After that, get the inflated view:

```
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_layout_name, null);
```

And add it to parent:

```
addView(v);
```